# Cross account access to Athena/Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Is it possible to **directly** access Athena and Glue **in another account** via EC2/EMR? I want to avoid maintaining the data catalog on in my AWS account and reuse the existing catalog.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to apply [STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/index.html#cli-aws-sts), which allows the account (let's call it *Alpha*) on EMR assume a role of Athena account (let's call it *Beta*).

To achieve this, you need to create a role **(in IAM/Roles)** with permission **(permissions tab)** to Athena/GLUE in *Beta*. And add account *Alpha* as a trusted relationship **(trusted relationships tab)**.

After that, you are fine to call the [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) API from *Alpha*, which gives you a temporary credential (key, secret, and token) to perform actions as the role in account *Beta*.